# Centrar texto dentro de una columna

Tags: c#, windows-forms, mysql-workbench, itextsharp, itextpdf

Estoy creando un PDF en C# con itextsharp, tengo el siguiente código:
1.- Cómo centrar el texto dentro de la fila/celda TipoServicioR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.-Además tengo otra pregunta, cómo hago para que en el PDF un checkBox seleccionado me arroje un icono de paloma? (Ejemplo en celdaNull8 / checkBox18),
Agrego foto de como se imprime el PDF.

```
PdfPCell TipoServicioR = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Tipo de servicio realizado:", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));

TipoServicioR.Rowspan = 6 ;                    
table3.AddCell(TipoServicioR);

PdfPCell celdaMp= new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Mantenimiento Preventivo", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaMp.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaMp);

PdfPCell celdaMC = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaMC.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaMC);

PdfPCell celdaRE = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Condiciones en que se deja el equipo", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaRE.Rowspan = 6;
table3.AddCell(celdaRE);

PdfPCell celdaEA = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Funcionando correctamente", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaEA.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaEA);

PdfPCell celdaOtros = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaOtros.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaOtros);
   
//Segunda hilera de la tabla 

PdfPCell celdaMc = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Mantenimiento Correctivo", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaMc.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaMc);

PdfPCell celdaNull = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull);
   

PdfPCell celdaFP = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Funcionando parcialmente", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaFP.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaFP);

PdfPCell celdaNull2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull2.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull2);

//Tercera hilera de la tabla

PdfPCell RE = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Revision de Equipo", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
RE.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(RE);

PdfPCell celdaNull3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull3.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull3);


PdfPCell FS = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Fuera de servicio", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
FS.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(FS);

PdfPCell celdaNull4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull4.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull4);

//Cuarta Hilera de La Tabla

PdfPCell EA = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Entrega de Accesorios", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
EA.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(EA);

PdfPCell celdaNull5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull5.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull5);


PdfPCell BE = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Baja de Equipos", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
BE.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(BE);

PdfPCell celdaNull6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull6.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull6);

//Quinta Hilera de La Tabla
PdfPCell O1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Otros", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
O1.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(O1);

PdfPCell celdaNull7 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull7.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull7);


PdfPCell O2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Otros", FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
O2.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(O2);

PdfPCell celdaNull8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("" + checkBox18.Checked,  FontFactory.GetFont("arial", 8, BaseColor.BLACK)));
celdaNull8.Colspan = 1;
table3.AddCell(celdaNull8);

doc.Add(table3);

doc.Close();
```